# How can I ignore undefined values when updating Firestore data from a Google Cloud Function?

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

In my index.js file, I have:

```
const db = admin.firestore();
db.settings({ignoreUndefinedProperties:true});
```

In my other .js file with the actual function, I have:

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const {Client, ReverseGeocodingLocationType, AddressType} = require("@googlemaps/google-maps-services-js");

async function addLocationData(addressComponents, reference){
    cityName = getLocationType(addressComponents, 'locality')
    stateName = getLocationType(addressComponents, 'administrative_area_level_1')
    countryName = getLocationType(addressComponents, 'country')
    await reference.set({
        'location.city': cityName,
        'location.state': stateName,
        'location.country': countryName
    },{ignoreUndefinedProperties:true})
    return true
}
```

However, I am still getting this error:

> Value for argument "data" is not a valid Firestore document. Cannot use "undefined" as a Firestore value (found in field "`location.city`"). If you want to ignore undefined values, enable `ignoreUndefinedProperties`.

The city data in this case is undefined, but I want to ignore undefined data.

Comment: Use an `if` statement that checks whether any of the variables are undefined?

Comment: @Barmar My goal is to set all defined values and ignore any undefined values in a single update call. So if I use if statements, wouldn't I need to account for 8 cases, where each of the values is either defined or undefined? Using 2^n cases seems unsustainable if the number of values grows.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`ignoreUndefinedProperties:true`  is not a valid SetOption

Reference for SetOptions:
https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/v8/firebase.firestore.SetOptions

You could pass `merge: true` and omit fields to leave them unchanged.

You still need a code change to not pass keys that are unchanged.

```
async function addLocationData(addressComponents, reference){
    cityName = getLocationType(addressComponents, 'locality')
    stateName = getLocationType(addressComponents, 'administrative_area_level_1')
    countryName = getLocationType(addressComponents, 'country')
    const data = {}
    if (cityName != null) { 
      data['city.name'] = cityName;
    }
    // etc
    await reference.set(data, {merge: true})
    return true
}
```